# how to add Sqlite database to my project?

Tags: android, database, eclipse, android-sqlite

I am working on (Quiz)Android Project. Now, I am trying to work with database. I got many tutorials for manipulating Sq-lite database operations. But my problem is where and how should I add the .db file in to the application. In package explorer of Eclipse IDE, under which folder group I need to add the .db file? and how to add question in my Sqlite database to my project.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: SQlite is in build db no need to create db files just refer this tutorials http://developer.android.com/training/notepad/index.html#preparing

Comment: oh..can u tell me what is difference between notepad or sqlLite data browser database.

Comment: notepad tutorial covers the entire SQlite database like add,edit,delete you go through and create db for your app.

Comment: sqlLite data browser is used to view your DB.You can download and install in your machine.

Comment: ok. it also help me to protect the my database.

Comment: I can't understand protect.

Comment: basically i am working on quiz porject..but if i want to upload it online then how it behave .

Comment: upload in the sense are you going to upload the application in online or host the application like combine with PHP.

Comment: See my answer and check it demo quiz are available.

Comment: Are you using external .db file???

Comment: I wanted to use external database to collect information about the users.but for question purpose i wanted to insert .db file in the assert file .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creation of database ..

[Creation of Database link..](http://developer.android.com/training/notepad/index.html#preparing)

See the following quiz demos it will create some idea to you.

[Demo1](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-ui-workshop-build-an-interactive-quiz-app/)

[Demo 2](https://github.com/robhinds/AndroidChuckQuiz)

[Demo3](http://www.sourcecodester.com/android/5121/android-quiz-demo-apss.html)

To refer the following for your requirement..

[quiz 1 link](http://maxood-android-corner.blogspot.in/2010/08/developing-quiz-app-on-android.html)

[quiz 2 link](http://www.developerfeed.com/android/tutorial/simple-quiz-game-andriod)

replace to button instead of radio button above link...

[quiz 3 link](http://automateddeveloper.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/getting-started-complete-android-app.html)...

Comment: hi!! i am going through second Demo.so how can i open the database of the project.

Comment: you can't see the DB directly in the project you can implement the project then only you can able to see the DB. Implement the project then we will discuss the DB.

Comment: I wanted to add layout with four button option.so when i clicked on the right button it move to the second option if not it show error like (KBC show).so can any one help me how to proceed.not we all select the question and lastly it show answer.

Comment: you can go through the first demo it will have the same what you want.

Comment: yeah !i have gone through that but still its image and I have to create database .I hope u understand my mind.

Comment: you can replace the image to button.

Comment: I have done that on My four button but m not going anywhere after that.

Comment: Do u have some tut links Like KBC game.It helps me lot.

Comment: I dont know KBC can you tell me....

Comment: i got it..you need put the button and set the answers and listeners..if particular button is clicked then increase the answer value other wise reduce...finally calculate the answer.

Comment: refer my edited answer...

Comment: ok..but still i have less idea how it work.I wanted to take help from second demo but it confused me as it moves from one java file to other .and in last it does't work.:(

Comment: do one thing post this to a separate question then only other should give some suggestion you will get some idea.

Comment: if you satisfy with my answer for your previous problem means you can click my answer it will help to beginners.

Comment: ok...but i can't get the right answer.

Comment: your previous question is how to create DB right.Then how you say that not right answer.

Comment: As u told me go for the this first so haven't gone through that .so, I will give credit when I worked on it.Don't worry.

Answer (score 1):

Your db default path will be :

```
//data/data/<Your-Application-Package-Name>/databases/<your-database-name>
```

You can put and open the database from wherever you like :

```
SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("/sdcard/mydatabase.db", null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
```

Comment: hi! i am following this link:-http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/

Answer (score 0):

SQLite builds the local database for you automatically. So you really have to do nothing at all. This makes sense as the app creates the database on your DEVICE and not on your workspace.   Else another user wouldnt be able to use the app as he won't be able accessing a database in your workspace.

Comment: ok.so how can i create my database .

Comment: ok .so sqlLite data browser database create the local database so when i upload my app it help me to access my local database.